# creating a trigger that executes sql statement over ssh in mysql

Tags: mysql, database-design, ssh, percona

I have 2 (th and ct) servers that are completely separated each with it's own database I want to sync a table(et) in th with ct
    I want if new inserts are done in table th a trigger will fire a ssh connection to ct server and insert the new rows I think the script should look something like the following  but I can't figure out the syntax

```
 DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS et-sync
CREATE TRIGGER et-sync AFTER INSERT ON th.et
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
 ssh user@11.11.2.11 "mysql -uroot -ppassword -e \"INSERT  db_testplus.user SET t = NEW.t;""
END;
```

and should I use this or just use Percona Toolkit for MySQL
(pt-table-sync) as I don't think adding a tool to control database sync at that scale is worth it(added complexity)

I know that adding replicas is properly the best solution but considering the current system design I thought of postponing the redesign of ct database for some time as it will take sometime to make it from scratch and it's an important part for the business

any suggestions ??

Comment: Looks a bad idea to me. What happens if the remote is down or a network fail? Loss of sync? How bad is that? Also, password in plain text is a smell. How tightly do they have to sync? How critical is this? How big is the database?

Comment: ct is around half GB and th is about +100 MB  .. ct is  a real-time examination server th is for purchasing exam keys and see exam results report what do you recommend ??

Comment: I recommend taking this to the professional server- and network-admin stack exchange site.

Comment: ok thanks  so much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For security reasons, MySQL does not allow launching processes from within itself.

Usually the alternative is to make a `cron` job to do orchestrate the actions, reaching into the database as needed to communicate and coordinate.

Comment: mmm I think it's better then to follow the pattern of MySQL and don't reinvent the wheel with triggers and just use replicas thanks :)